# Java object graph -> xml when direction of object association needs to be reversed

Tags: xml, jpa, jaxb, jaxb2

A java application I am working on has objects with a relationship similar to below. In the real application both objects are JPA entities.

```
class Underlying{}

class Thing
{
  private Underlying underlying;

  public Underlying getUnderlying()
  {
    return underlying;
  }

  public void setUnderlying(final Underlying underlying)
  {
    this.underlying = underlying;
  }
}
```

There is a requirement in the application to create xml of the form:

`<template>
     <underlying>
        <thing/>
        <thing/>
        <thing/>
     </underlying>
</template>`

So we have a situation where the object graph expresses the relationship between Thing and Underlying in the opposite direction to how it's expressed in the xml.

I expect to use JAXB to create the xml but ideally I don't want to have to create a new object hierarchy to reflect the associations in the xml. Is there any way to create xml of the form required from the entities in their current form (through the use of xml annotations or something)? I don't have any experience using JAXB but from the limited research I've done it doesn't seem like it's possible to reverse the direction of association in any straightforward way. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated. One other option that has been suggested is to use XLST to transform the xml into the correct format. I have done no research on this topic as yet but I'll add to the question when I have some more info.

Thanks,

Matt.

Comment: @Sigmoidal: If you want an XSLT solution then you need to post input sample and desired output, otherwise the question would be not well defined for XSLT. Retagging

Comment: @Alejandro well, his input would be 
    element template { 
        element thing {
             element underlying+
        }*
    }
and his output would be:
    element template {
        element underlying {
             element thing*
        }*
    }

Comment: @Sigmoidal you'll want to consider what the use-case is for expressing the tree grouped by `<underlying/>`.  Does it sometimes make sense for your application to operate on the data this way?  It might be worth the effort of the alternative data structure.  If it doesn't work for your app, does the external XML format really make sense for another application? It might be worth arguing about.  How big is the graph?

Comment: @Sigmoidal will you be reading the alien format or just writing it?

Comment: @David Bullock: Hi David, thanks for the response. Unfortunately, for now at least the external XML format cannot be changed. With respect to the graph size, there are ~1000 Underlyings each with ~50 associated Things. Or looking at it the other way, ~50,000 Things each linking to one of ~1000 Underlyings.

Comment: @David Bullock: We'll be reading and writing the alien format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is making a instance of Underlying aware of the related instances of Thing.  Below are a couple approaches you could leverate.

**Option #1 - Make the Relationship Bidirectional**

The easiest thing to do would be to make the relationship bidirectional.  Then you could leverage the @XmlInverseReference extension in [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php). Note:  I'm the MOXy tech lead:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/jpa-entities-to-xml-bidirectional.html

**Option #2 - Use an XmlAdapter**

You could create an adapted version of Underlying.  When building the adapted Underlying object the XmlAdapter could query the instances of Thing to populate the things property:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html

Comment: @Blaise Doughan: that is pretty cool stuff, and improved my knowledge-of/respect-for JAXB.  However, can these strategies be used to address the requirement that the output is *grouped by* `<underlying/>`?

Comment: @David Bullock:  My assumption is that The 
"underlying" element corresponds to an instance of Underlying.  If so then grouped by is not an issue (assuming of the the two proposed options is taken).  If Underlying on the other hand corresponds to "Template" then the XmlElementWrapper annotation can be used:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

Comment: @Blaise Doughan: Thanks for the response. The Xml Adapter option looks interesting but would still mean I'd have to create a new hierarchy of objects to map to. I don't really want to make underlyings aware of things so the bi-directional mapping approach isn't ideal but it seems this would be the only way to resuse the current object hierarchy. Thanks for the advice, I have some thinking to do.

Comment: @Sigmoidal - You wouldn't require an entirely new hierarchy, only an AdaptedUnderlying class.  The XmlAdapter would convert this class to/from Underlying.

Comment: @Blaise Doughan: Sorry, am struggling to 'get it'. `Thing` has only one `Underlying`, but an `Underlying` might apply to many `Thing`s.  So we give our `Template` to be marshalled, and JAXB iterates through all the `Thing` instances.  At each instance, it extracts the `Underlying`.  But we can't just emit an `<underlying>` with a `<thing>` inside it.  No, we have to wait until it has read ALL model, when it knows, for each `<underlying/>` exactly which `<thing/>`s it contains.  I don't get how `XmlAdapter` helps here.  Nor does MOXy `@XmlInverstReference` annotation have an example for 1:many.

Comment: @David Bullock - @XmlInverseReference requires that changes be made to the object model to give Underlying a collection of Thing.  @XmlInverseReference is able to populate the bidirectional relationship during an unmarshal.  XmlAdapter would require the creation of an AdaptedUnderlying class with a property of type List<Thing>.  Since JPA is being used the XmlAdapter could query for the instances of Thing that refer to Underlying and use the result to populate the list property.

Comment: @Blaise Doughan: Looking a bit closer at the XML adapter solution I realised my 'new object hierarchy' comment was wrong. I'll definitely give it a try. I should have time over the next few days. I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

JAXB may not the right approach in your case.  JAXB is best when you need to round-trip the object model to XML and back, and you've got some latitude either with the XML or the object model.  In this case, you seem to have no latitude.  No JAXB for you, IMHO.

That's a non-trivial number of XML elements, too, considering you'll be sorting them somewhere.  Probably on the expensive side to have the whole graph *and* a sorted copy in memory?  So you'll want to fetch the `Thing`s from the JPA datastore ordered by `Underlying` (let the database do the sorting), and stream this to a `javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter` for output.

On the input side, use a `javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader`.

Comment: @Sigmoidal I think this is your best bet.  The JAXB approach requires an in-memory sort, either to transform the graph to a model suitable for input/output before you serialise it to XML, or after you serialise it to XML (with XSLT or by swapping in your own XMLStreamReader/Writer implementations when umarshalling/marshalling the XML with JAXB).  This approach doesn't *require* the whole state of the object model to be in memory twice.

Answer (score 1):

Struggling with a similar issue, I just came across an additional possibility:

- Add the parent reference property to your JAXB annotated classes
- Annotate the property with @XmlTransient
- Implement the method `public void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller u, Object parent)`
- Implement the logic to set the parent pointer in this method like this: `this.parent= (ParentType) parent;` Of course you can to more stuff in that method.

The method is called by JAXB after unmarshalling, as the name implies.

References: (Rather old) [discussion on forums.java.net](http://forums.java.net/node/654639), [JAXB Guide](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_cyclic_references_to_XML.html)

I cannot use @XmlInverseReference since we are using a different JAXB implementation than MOXy.
While I came to appreciate @XmlAdapter, I find this approach simpler as it does not require additional classes.

While this does not match your problem description completely, I still think this could help future readers.